# Office Online Server for SharePoint 2016 SQL Server compatability

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2016

What versions of SQL SERVER are supported by Office Online Server for SharePoint 2016? I am not referring to the environment the OOS2016 is hosted on, I am referring to the environments it could query from.

Answer (score 0):

OOS does not query SQL Server... it offers web services to SharePoint, Exchange and other systems. SharePoint may deliver document content to OOS that originated in SQL Server, but OOS does not access that file directly from the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm fairly sure that our excel files are connected to the SSAS 2008 right now to access the cube, and furthermore, we have some that query the database through the "refresh" button. I believe you may be wrong in that sense, because they do reach the SQL Server

Comment: Actually here is a link that mentions SQL Server is indeed a source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/work-with-external-data-in-excel-services-sharepoint-server-a00e5a66-017e-4956-bd40-49639ad1f1d0

Comment: That link is about Excel Services, not OOS. Excel Services runs on a SharePoint Server and uses a SQL database accessed through SharePoint. Here's the requirements for OOS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/plan-office-online-server#software-hardware-and-configuration-requirements-for-office-online-server  and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/deploy-office-online-server

Comment: "our excel files are connected to the SSAS 2008" Those are data connections from the Excel file to data source. Requirements there depend on the SQL statements and SQL features the Excel file is using. You would need to ask the owners of those Excel files what their SQL requirements are.

Comment: Here's some info on data connections from Excel running in OOS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/configure-excel-online-data-refresh-by-using-external-data-connections-in-office